# Objective - C How to manage multiple views with View Controller iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, view

I am new in developing iOS apps. I am trying to develop a multiple views app. My doubt is how to manage a multiple views app with View Controller, I mean, I do not want to use Navigation Controller nor Tab Controller.

My idea is to show a first View to choose the language, and after this, I want to show some different profiles in a table view. When you choose the profile, you get into a menu where you have some different functionalities (Once in this menu, I might use Navigation Controller).

My problem is that I don't know how to manage these two first views. I don't know if I have to declare them in the appDelegate, or if I can do it nesting one to other, I mean, I do the first view, and when I pressed the button, I declare the new view. Once in the new view, when I pressed a row in the table view, I make the another view.

I know it is a little bit confusing, so I hope you could understand it quite well.

EDIT:

I want to clarify that I am not using storyboards. My main doubt is what to do with all de view controllers, Do I have to declare all of them in the appDelegate? or Can I declare each view in every controller?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards, you can use Segue's to navigate between the views, so you would show your first view, then you could tie a button to the next view (by control dragging in storyboard).  If you want to transition programmatically you can use the performSegueWithIdentifier method.  You could use the same approach to get from your tableViewController to your next viewController by using the performSegueWithIdentifier method from within the tableViewController's didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method (i.e. when a user taps a cell).

That should get you started.  Good luck!

EDIT:

You really should be using storyboards.  It's the way to do things these days.  If you refuse, then the best approach is to create a container view controller that manages your "children" view controllers.  You can find information on doing this, as well as the methods needed to present/remove child view controllers here:

[Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigation controller with "hidden" property.

self.navController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have two different views and transition between them, you will want to use UIViewControllers presented modally.  Here is [Apple's Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html) to this.